# build errors with swig and javascript/node

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, swig

I'm getting Swig set up on OSX with a very simple build example, but I'm running into compilation errors - looks like the swig wrapper is building a bunch of code that the underlying v8 system doens't like at all.

I have tried reducing the nodejs version to 8.x.x but still no luck.

Has anyone had any similar issues and worked out the correct solution?

Swig is 4.0.3 via brew
also installed v8 view brew
node is v8.17.0 via nvm (or v12.18.0 - system default)
node-gyp is v7.0.0

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/example/example_wrap.o
../example_wrap.cxx:903:47: warning: 'NewFromUtf8' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  SWIGV8_THROW_EXCEPTION(v8::Exception::Error(SWIGV8_STRING_NEW(msg)));
                                              ^
../example_wrap.cxx:826:44: note: expanded from macro 'SWIGV8_STRING_NEW'
#define SWIGV8_STRING_NEW(str) v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), str)
                                           ^
/Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/v8.h:3030:10: note: 'NewFromUtf8' has been
      explicitly marked deprecated here
  static V8_DEPRECATED(
         ^
/Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro
      'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../example_wrap.cxx:938:7: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
  v8::Handle<v8::Value> err;
  ~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:933:32: warning: 'NewFromUtf8' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    err = v8::Exception::Error(SWIGV8_STRING_NEW(msg));
                               ^
../example_wrap.cxx:826:44: note: expanded from macro 'SWIGV8_STRING_NEW'
#define SWIGV8_STRING_NEW(str) v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), str)
                                           ^
/Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/v8.h:3030:10: note: 'NewFromUtf8' has been
      explicitly marked deprecated here
  static V8_DEPRECATED(
         ^
/Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro
      'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:65: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:48: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                           ~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:67: error: use of undeclared identifier 'objRef'
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                                  ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:80: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                                          ~~~~ ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:82: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ptr'
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                                                 ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:87: error: unexpected type name 'swig_type_info': expected expression
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                                                      ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:103: error: use of undeclared identifier 'info'
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                                                                      ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:113: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                                                                            ~~~ ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1003:119: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
SWIGRUNTIME int SWIG_V8_ConvertInstancePtr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> objRef, void **ptr, swig_type_info *info, int flags) {
                                                                                                                      ^
                                                                                                                      ;
../example_wrap.cxx:1276:1: warning: inline variables are a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]
SWIGRUNTIMEINLINE
^
../example_wrap.cxx:216:40: note: expanded from macro 'SWIGRUNTIMEINLINE'
# define SWIGRUNTIMEINLINE SWIGRUNTIME SWIGINLINE
                                       ^
../example_wrap.cxx:55:23: note: expanded from macro 'SWIGINLINE'
#   define SWIGINLINE inline
                      ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1277:44: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
int SwigV8Packed_Check(v8::Handle<v8::Value> valRef) {
                                  ~~~~~~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:1277:28: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
int SwigV8Packed_Check(v8::Handle<v8::Value> valRef) {
                       ~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:1277:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'valRef'
int SwigV8Packed_Check(v8::Handle<v8::Value> valRef) {
                                             ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1277:53: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
int SwigV8Packed_Check(v8::Handle<v8::Value> valRef) {
                                                    ^
                                                    ;
../example_wrap.cxx:1472:17: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
SWIGRUNTIME v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> SWIGV8_CreateClassTemplate(const char* symbol) {
            ~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:1476:31: warning: 'NewFromUtf8' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    class_templ->SetClassName(SWIGV8_SYMBOL_NEW(symbol));
                              ^
../example_wrap.cxx:827:44: note: expanded from macro 'SWIGV8_SYMBOL_NEW'
#define SWIGV8_SYMBOL_NEW(sym) v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), sym)
                                           ^
/Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/v8.h:3030:10: note: 'NewFromUtf8' has been
      explicitly marked deprecated here
  static V8_DEPRECATED(
         ^
/Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.0/include/node/v8config.h:328:29: note: expanded from macro
      'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1478:34: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> inst_templ = class_templ->InstanceTemplate();
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:1478:9: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
    v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> inst_templ = class_templ->InstanceTemplate();
    ~~~~^
../example_wrap.cxx:1478:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'inst_templ'; did you mean 'class_templ'?
    v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> inst_templ = class_templ->InstanceTemplate();
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                   class_templ
../example_wrap.cxx:1475:37: note: 'class_templ' declared here
    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> class_templ = SWIGV8_FUNCTEMPLATE_NEW_VOID();
                                    ^
../example_wrap.cxx:1479:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'inst_templ'
    inst_templ->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
4 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/example/example_wrap.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/Data-4TB-2020/Users/mark/Development/node/fcpx
gyp ERR! node -v v8.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```